# Jquery +/- points

Tags: jquery

This is a game were a user enters a random number, then clicks "Play", they'll see a set of boxes appear with randomly generated numbers. The object of the game is to click on the box that has your number to build points.

How can I make it so, they lose points if they don't click on the box that has their number.

see game here: [link text](http://gamerholic.com/pickanumber.php)

solutions I've tried.

```
 if ($('#randomnumber li').hasClass('')) {
    if (parseInt($this.text(), 10) === n) {
        $this.addClass('wrong');
        $('#hitcount').text(--hitCount);
    } 
}
```

thought the .attr('class', '') gave all li's a '' class

```
  if ($('<li />').hasClass('')) {
    if (parseInt($this.text(), 10) === n) {
        $this.addClass('wrong');
        $('#hitcount').text(--hitCount);
    } 
}
```

Tried several other variations of the above code including

```
if($('#randomnumbers li')not.('Clicked')
```

nothing worked

here's the complete script

```
var hitCount = 0,
missCount = 0;

         function IsNumeric(n) {
return !isNaN(n);
}

         $("#getit").click(function() {
//Resets Game to 0 points

var hitCount = 0,
missCount = 0;
$('#misscount').text(0);
$('#hitcount').text(0);
$('#message').hide(100);        
$('#randomnumber').empty();
$('#randomnumber').show(300);

//starts game get users value

var li = [],
    intervals = 0,
    n = parseInt($('#MyNumber').val());

//set game speed

if (IsNumeric(n)) {
   intervalId= setInterval(function() {
        li[intervals++ % li.length].text(Math.random() > .1 ? Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 + n) + (n / 2)) : n).attr('class', '')    ;
    }, <?php echo $time ?>);
 }

 //empty all numbers in the boxes 

$('#randomnumber').empty();

 //generate new boxes 

for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    li.push($('<li />').one('click', function() {
        BoxClick.call(this, n);
    }).appendTo('#randomnumber'));
}

//get which box is clicked 

function BoxClick(n) {
var $this = $(this);
$('#randomnumber li').unbind().one('click', function() {
        BoxClick.call(this,n);
});
$this.unbind();

//add points if the box clicked matches the users value, subtract points if they don't.

    if (!$this.hasClass('clicked')) {
    if (parseInt($this.text(), 10) === n) {
        $this.addClass('correct');
        $('#hitcount').text(++hitCount);
    } else {
        $this.addClass('wrong');
        $('#misscount').text(++missCount);
    }
 }
     //if user gets three misses submit score to database

            if(missCount==<?php echo $limit ?>){
               clearInterval(intervalId);
               $('#randomnumber').hide(300);

                $.ajax({
type : 'POST',
url : 'FBhighscore_hwnd.php',
dataType : 'json',
data: {
tgameid: $('#tgameid').val(),MyNumber: $('#MyNumber').val(),totalHits: hitCount
},
success : function(data){
$('#waiting').hide(500);
$('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
.text(data.msg).show(500);
if (data.error === true)
$('#loginForm').show(500);
else
$('#send').hide(500);       
},
error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
$('#waiting').hide(500);
$('#message').removeClass().addClass('error')
.text('There was an error.').show(500);
$('#loginForm').show(500);
}
});

            }


$this.addClass('clicked');
}
return false;
});
```

Comment: @John - I mean this very constructively, which you should know since I helped out yesterday, but this isn't a place to go to have people solve all your problems for you.  If you are stuck on something, or are struggling with an idea conceptually, people will be more than happy to help.  However, if you ask people to write all your code for you, or as in this case, ask how to accomplish a feature without showing that you've at least tried it, your welcome will run out quickly.  Just friendly advice :)

Comment: Of that entire code the items I had the most difficulty with are the one's I ask for help with. None of my post's are simply blank questions saying do this for me without my code already attached.

Saying I haven't at least tried is a little offensive.

In the past I've offered cash to folks who help, I even asked for other games that I can add to my service.

Comment: @John - I apologize, I don't mean to imply that you haven't tried.  The problem is that we can't SEE what/that you've tried. You might try updating the question with a description of approaches that you tried and where you were coming up short.  Code examples are also great, but try to limit it to the code that you are having difficulty with. IMHO, it's better to provide a small amount of code and have people need to ask for a bit more context, than to provide a lot of irrelevant code that an answerer will have to sift through.

Comment: I'll happily post the MANY variations i've tried to solve this. This is not something simple.

Comment: Please do! That will allow us to give specific suggestions, and that way we won't spend a lot of time thinking of solutions that you have already tried.  We do want to help!

Comment: In the vein of trying to be helpful, have you reviewed the "How to Ask" page? You can see it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask  If I were to ask this question, I would say something like "I am trying to implement feature X.  I have tried to do this using techniques A, B, and C (probably provide code sample of said techniques) but I am having trouble with Y.  Any ideas for what I should do next?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already tagging a box with the "correct" class when the user clicks the correct answer, couldn't you just check for the lack of that class when you change a box's number?  Something along the lines of this:

```
function ChangeBoxNumber(box) {
   if (parseInt(box.text(), 10) === n && !box.hasClass('correct')) {
       //missed answer, you lose a point!
   }
   //change number
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I don't know if you are part of the site but if you are please consider adding a subscription option. until I get to as good as you at this, I'll have a ton of questions some good some bad. Hope that's okay.

Comment: I'm not saying this worked Ender, I'm just saying thanks for your help.

Comment: @John This site is largely community-driven; Anybody can ask questions and anybody can answer them.

Comment: The Above solution doesn't work. I'll go post a request on guru.com and play someone in india $5 to solve this for me.

Comment: @John **There** is the disconnect. *You* think Stack Overflow should be all about solving your problems. It isn't. It's about learning how to solve problems yourself.

Comment: @meagar - I wish I could vote that comment up more than once.

Comment: @Ender Thanks. I just don't get some people. We're under no obligation, we *try* to be helpful, and he throws it back in our face.